# Sharing non-boolean variables between threads

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables, variable-assignment

I am using Vosk to make an audio player. I have created two functions: One to play the music and one to listen out for the user saying anything.

```
keywords = ['keyword', 'keyword', 'keyword', 'keyword', 'keyword']

stop = False

def playMusic(music): #This one plays the music while 'stop' is false
    while audio.is_set():
        music.play()
        time.sleep(music.get_length())
        break
    return

def checkwhileplaying(): #This one checks for any new messages from the user
    audio.set()
    data = q.get()
    if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
        time.sleep(1)
        if rec.Result()[2] == 't': #This puts the output as one simple sentence instead of 
            message = rec.Result()[14:-3]
        else:
            message = rec.Result()[17:-3]
    else:
        if rec.PartialResult()[2] == 't':
            time.sleep(1)
            message = rec.PartialResult()[14:-3]
        else:
            message = rec.PartialResult()[17:-3]
    for x in keywords:
        if x in message:
            music = ('filepath/filepath/file.wav')
    if 'stop' in stopmessage:
        audio.clear()
    
play = threading.Thread(target=playMusic,args=(stop,), daemon=True)
audio = threading.Event()
check = threading.Thread(target=checkwhileplaying, daemon=True)
audio.set()
play.start()
check.start()
```

The idea is that while the listen function is listening, if it detects a keyword, it will set the 'music' function as a file, which the play function will play.

How would I share the variables between the threads? I'm new to python and don't know much about global variables, static variables, etc.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You may be interested in the singleton pattern.

Comment: You say you "don't know much about global variables",  but that's exactly what `keywords`, `stop`, `play`, `audio` and `check` are.  It's no more complicated than that.  One way to do what you're asking is to use a `queue`.  The listener pushes things to do on the queue, and the other thread pops things from the queue and does them.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for the suggestion! I now know that queues are the solution to my problem. Could you give me a gist of how would I structure the code? I haven't used queues before.

Comment: I think I gave you the structure.  Your `checkwhileplaying` would use `q.put` to add a filename to the list of things to do.  Your `playMusic` would be in an infinite loop, and would do `q.get` to wait for something to do.  `q.get` blocks, so it doesn't waste CPU cycles.